# Facebook login with Django and Javascript

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-login

I want to implement a Facebook login on my website that runs with Django. I have found a really good post explaining how to use the Facebook Javascript SDK here: https://www.sammyk.me/best-practice-for-facebook-login-with-the-javascript-sdk-and-php-sdk-v4-1

My problem is that I need to be able to access the facebook token from server side code. It seems this token is encrypted in a cookie and we can decrypt this cookie using the PHP SDK (as stated in the part "Using the JavaScript SDK and PHP SDK together" from the article).
However, I don't use PHP. Is there a simple way in Python to get this access token? Can I get it using the javascript SDK and maybe send an AJAX request to my server?
If not, do I need to manualy build a login flow?

Comment: Log the response object that `FB.login` gives you to console. and see what it contains …

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I can get the token using only javascript using `var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];`. I can then send it to my server.